# Map and multimap : memory usage / management differences?

Tags: c++, memory, dictionary, multimap

I wrote a program that have to read a big file with operator>> , count some stuff and insert datas (string and int) in a multimap.
The problem is that the program crashes and it seems to be a memory problem (it works well with small files).
I think that it reaches the memory allocation limit of Windows.

What I tried : 
I made a 32-bit and an 64-bit versions.
As you know, Windows has a memory allocation limit that is not the same for 32bits and 64bits builds.
With both it crashes.
I looked the performance tab of the task manager to observe the memory consumption.
32-bit : the program crashes every time it reaches 5.3 GB.
64-bit : the memory consumption of the program continually increases until it reaches the whole RAM of the system and crashes.

I tried with a map instead of a multimap : the program never crashes and stay stable at roughly 3.5 GB (32-bit and 64-bit builds) all along the program execution.

So, do you know if there is a difference between map and multimap in terms of memory usage or memory management ? 
Or is it just because map do not allows duplicate keys ?

Comment: Have you compared the number of elements in each container? Obviously there's a difference between storing something once and storing it many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there is. Did you read descriptions?

[`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map):

> std::map is a sorted associative container that contains key-value pairs with **unique keys**. Keys are sorted by using the comparison function Compare.

[`std::map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert):

> **Return value**:
>   1-2) Returns a pair consisting of an iterator to the inserted element (or to the element that prevented the insertion) and a bool denoting whether the insertion took place.

You cannot have two same keys, so you overwrite values under the same key, you don't allocate any new space.

[`std::multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/insert):

> Multimap is an associative container that contains a sorted list of key-value pairs.

[`std::multimap::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/insert) cannot "fail", it always return an iterator because, it always adds new association. So adding items under the same key in a loop will allocate new memory.

Similar is true for every multi-container (set, unordered map, *etc.*). They are semantically different.

Comment: Ok, thank you, now this is clear! I'm new to c++ and programming in general so these descriptions on cppreference are difficult to understand. Do you know how I could solve this problem (make the program not to crash) ?

Comment: I meant no offence, but it's kinda like RTFM, though I tried to point out and explain important parts (which is basically what KerrekSB wrote in his comment) I hope you'll manage to read *technical* soon enough, it's useful =).